# Generic return object for a collection of objects in RESTful Spring3 app

Tags: java, spring, rest, collections, jaxb

I am looking for a generic way of returning a set of objects in my REST service. I use the Spring3 message-converters and the @ResponseBody annotation.

Some sites say that JAXB2 has "problems" returning a standard java.util.List, and all examples found define a dedicated class (e.g. Authors, Products, Customers) for each data domain, such as:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-spring3webserv/index.html
(see "Collection of resources", second paragraph)

Has anyone found a way to provide a generic class/approach for this that spares me creating all those collection classes?

**Update 5th April 2011:** I haven't really made any progress on this. Returning a generic list object always results in a JAXBException "class XXX nor any of its super class is known to this context"

Answer (score 1):

When creating REST services in a JAX-RS framework (which uses JAXB for XML binding) you can return a List.  For an example see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html

What happens when you try to do this with Spring?

Comment: Sending the REST request with an Accept header of "application/xml" results in a 406 NOT_ACCEPTABLE status code. Serializing to JSON via "application/json" media type works. Previously I also had some weird 500 Internal Server errors without any log or console output at all, but can't reproduce that now.. (of course!) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just return a ModelMap and put whatever objects you want in there including arrays.

Comment: Really? Although, as stated in my question, I am using the @ResponseBody annotation??

Answer (score 0):

Wondering ... did you set the Content-Type : application/xml in the request headers?